# Using navigation property in orderby clause of breeze query

Tags: breeze, asp.net-web-api

I am using breeze to call a web api method which is:

```
Repository.ShipmentAppeals.Where(sa => sa.ShipmentID == shipmentID).Select(sa => sa.Appeal).Include("Case");
```

My breeze query looks like:

```
var query = EntityQuery.from('GetEditShipmentAppeals')
            .withParameters({ shipmentID: shipmentID, caseID: caseID })
            .orderByDesc("Case.ID")
```

GetEditShipmentAppeals is a web api method that contains the first query. In spite of using .Include("Case") in the query I am not able to use "Case.ID" in the order by clause of breeze query.

```
 var query = EntityQuery.from('Appeals')
                .expand("Case,Patient")
                .orderByDesc("Case.ID").inlineCount();
```

Even if I use navigation property on a breeze query that does not involve a EF query in web api, it does not work. In above query Case is a navigation property in Appeal table.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your example correctly, then I think that this is an Entity Framework issue.  My understanding is that Entity Framework does not support "Includes" on a projection.  See http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/347543/entity-framework-eager-loading-not-working-in-some-projection-scenarios.

To confirm this, I would try executing your EF query in isolation and see if the "Include" is actually doing anything. My guess is that it isnt.

However, you can still accomplish what you want with a slightly different server side projection.  ( I'm not sure what object 'Case' is a property of and the syntax may be a bit off but...) Something like:

```
Repository.ShipmentAppeals.Where(sa => sa.ShipmentID == shipmentID).Select(sa => new 
   { Appeal: sa.Appeal, Case: sa.Appeal.Case, CaseId: sa.Appeal.Case.Id });
```

Note that Breeze will return a collection of 'anonymous' javascript objects from this query, but each of the 'entities' within each of these objects (i.e. Appeals and Cases) will be full Breeze entities and will be part of the EntityManager cache.

Comment: I am sure that include is working on the EF query because I am using Case object's properties in knockout data binding and I can see the data being displayed. <td data-bind="text: Case().ID()"></td>

Comment: What is the name of the "Case" property on the client, and what is the name of it's "ID" property.  The orderBy clause takes client side property names.  I can't tell what your breeze NamingConvention  is but it may be that your orderBy clause should be orderByDesc("case.iD").  You can look into the metadataStore to determine what breeze thinks the property names actually are.

Comment: I have edited my question. Navigation property does not work in order by clause for a breeze query as well.

Comment: I am unable to repro this. Please take a look at the the Breeze DocCode samples in the Breeze zip available on the website. There are several examples of this working. I would also check whether you are  using a Breeze NamingConvention and if so check that the propertyNames in the metadataStore are what you think they are.